# Monitor CPU and memory for Azure WebJob

Tags: .net, azure, console-application, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I have setup application insights for a web app and I can see the performance figures such as CPU and memory consumed by the app. I have another app which contains only a webjob. How can I monitor CPU and memory consumed by the webjob? It is a .NET console application. I have added in the Nuget packages to the console app and I am able to manually register events to Application Insights - such as exceptions. For some reason though I am not getting performance data. Is this possible and how do I do it?

Comment: After a little more research it would appear that the web app is not working either. I can only get CPU and memory data into the azure portal when I debug locally in visual studio. As soon as I publish to my Azure web app it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot get performance counters from your Web App (App Service) with Application Insights. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160827104626/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/#performance-counters) and note the first sentence.

> **(Not for Azure web apps.)** Click Servers on the overview blade to ...

I would recommend looking at the link below for getting the CPU data for your App Service.

[Monitor service metrics](https://web.archive.org/web/20160827063439/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-how-to-customize-monitoring/)

Answer (score 0):

If third party tools are an option, look into [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) - it can monitor utilizatino metrics of WebApps with Webjobs on them as well as monitor for WebJobs and even restart them upon failure